# Whatsapp Message API - Message type text

Tags: curl, message, whatsapp

I am having problems invoking Meta's Whatsapp messaging API via curl.

I am trying to invoke the messages API from Facebook/Wahtsapp

It looks to me I am doing exactly what they're showing here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/messages#text-object

With this call

curl -i -X POST 
https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/XXXXX/messages 
-H 'Authorization: Bearer XYZ' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
-d '{ "messaging_product": "whatsapp", "recipient_type": "individual”, "to": "MY ACTUAL NUMBER", "type": “text”, “text”: { “body”: "this is my message”, “preview_url”:  false} }'

And I keep on getting

{"error":{"message":"(#100) The parameter messaging_product is required.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"ANYeVdITMw5XHnkTDVf_aO4"}}%